# I am developing and XDK app. Any correction with this code

Tags: javascript, android, jquery, html, intel-xdk

How can I select a paragraph contents in HTML using javascript such that I can apply a onclick function? Here is my code : When I click on the paragraph it selects all the paragraphs in the document but i only want it to select individual paragraph content

```
<script> 
function social_share() { 
      var quote = $("p").text();                          
      window.plugins.socialsharing.share("Follow me on twitter.", quote, null,"url",function(result){  
            alert('result: ' + result); 
            }, function(result){ 
            alert('error: ' + result); }); 
 } 
</script>
```

Some data

another paragraph

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This line:

```
var quote = $("p").text();
```

is selecting all the `p` elements (i.e. all the paragraphs), so `text()` from all `p` elements is all the text from all the paragraphs concatenated together.  You need to specify the specific paragraph selected.  There are a couple ways to do this.

If you want to specify `onclick` in the HTML code, you could do this:

```
<p onclick="social_share(this)">paragraph text</p>
```

but generally this is considered bad style.  Assuming you're using jQuery, a more fashionable solution might be to do this:

```
<p class='clickable'>pagagraph text</p>
. . .
function init() {
    var pgraphs = $(".clickable");
    pgraphs.click( function() {
        social_share($(this).text());
    }
}
```

Comment: `$(function(){ $("#main-body").on("click", "p", function(e){ // more code });` May be a better click listener/handler to set. That way, he can target all paragraphs in a given container, and then use e.target to react to the one that was clicked.